# cutoff and auc and changing cutoff

Tags: classification, roc, auc

can you tell me if this is ok?

While the AUC (i.e. AUC of 0.6) we got is acceptable since it's bigger than 0.5, we may need to re-evaluate at our cutoff selections again. Because we can select cutoffs by our choice, sensitivity and specificity would change if we switch a cutoff from 0.7 to 0.68, for example. Then, we may have to re-draw a ROC again if we set new cutoffs. For new cutoffs, sensitivity and specificity are going to be different and we may find the new AUC more acceptable. We may end up finding the existing cutoffs that we used were not that great.

Comment: This is a XY problem. You already have a procedure you are not confident will answer your problem, and, instead of asking about the problem directly, you are asking if your procedure is correct. It is often easier to answer the root question than explaining why something is wrong (as can be seen by the long comment chain).

Answer (score 3):

Your model is giving you values on a continuum, perhaps the interval $[0,1]$. The ROC curve is created by setting a threshold, calculating the sensitivity and specificity according to classifications based on if the prediction is above or below that threshold, and then doing it again for another threshold. Therefore, the ROC curve depends on those original predictions, not on the classifications made according to any particular threshold, so you have the same ROC curve no matter what threshold you select.

Comment: thanks, Dave. So, what you are saying is y^ is the one that makes the change to sensitivity and specificity. But, setting a different cutoff will make a change to sensitivity and specifciity. That is what I am talking about. Isn't mine good?

Comment: @ShawnKim I’m struggling to understand what you’re saying. Could you please rephrase or clarify?

Comment: You can pick a cutoff how-ever you want. If you set 10 cutoffs that are really high, then your specificity will be high and sensitivity will be low. Then, your AUC will be low. What I am saying is we can re-evaluate 10 cutoffs so that we can adjust the cutoffs to be lower. In that way, we can have higher sensitivities and lower specificities. Then, our adjusted AUC will be higher.

Comment: You have one ROC curve that gives many possible pairings of sensitivity and specificity, depending on the threshold.

Comment: yup. So, we may have only 5 cutoffs and we cannot get a clear picture of the true AUC. We cannot really cross validate to get the optimal cutoffs. So, we may want to choose other 10 cutoffs then we can hopefully have a better and more reliable AUC. Does my thought process make sense? thx

Comment: How are you calculating the ROC curve? Is it in a software package like `sklearn`.

Comment: I am just preparing for an exam. So, what that exam is saying we have to get cutoffs and get sensitivity and specificity. Then, we have to plot them into the ROC. Then, we find the AUC.

Comment: this is what the solution says: The fitted boosted tree can be used to produce, for each record being tested, a probability that the animal will be transferred. Then, the modeler separately decides the lowest probability, called the cutoff value, that will convert probabilities equal to and higher than that cutoff value to a prediction of transfer. Moving from left to right on the ROC curve represents all possibilities of the cutoff value, from 1 to 0, before this decision has been made.

Comment: The two points represent using different cutoff values, one lower and one higher, to determine class predictions from the probability predictions of the same predictive model.

Comment: I agree with this. What is the issue?

Comment: Can you tell me what the solution is saying at a high level then? I might be misunderstanding what teh solution is saying. Isn't the solution saying we have to find or re-evaluate different cutoffs?

Comment: The first two sentences of my answer say how to create a ROC curve. You’re evaluating different cutoffs to create the curve.

Comment: oh nevermind. This is what the solution is saying: While an AUC of 0.628 does indicate that the boosted tree is expected to perform better than random guessing (an AUC of 0.5), it only indicates that and does not by itself indicate an excellent model. The performance of the boosted tree at a particular cutoff point needs to be evaluated against other candidate models using a test metric more specifically aligned to the business problem to establish its excellence.

Comment: basically, we may need to find other cutoffs to evaluate again. Then, we may find a better AUC. I hope this is what the solution is saying

Comment: AUC means area under the (ROC) curve. How many ROC curves are there?

Comment: there is 1 ROC curve to calculate the AUC. So, you have to draw another ROC to calculate another AUC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148551/discussion-between-dave-and-shawn-kim).

Answer (score 3):

Brief answer: the AUC is threshold agnostic, it's one of its main selling points. Therefore, it makes no sense to talk about the impact of changing thresholds and AUC, since AUC does not use that information, and is instead derived from the continuous decision scores or probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

ROC, sensitivity, and specificity have nothing to do with decision making as they are all in reverse time and information-flow order.  Optimum decisions involve forward predictions (e.g., predicted probability of an event) and knowledge about consequences of those decisions (utility function).  See [this](https://www.fharrell.com/post/backwards-probs) for more.  Never dichotomize information at the front end.  You might possibly threshold a predicted probability (at the back end) but even then the use of dichotomization can be misleading.